# База данных населенных пунктов

Tags: база-данных

необходимо база данных населенных пунктов для всего мира с указанием примерного количества людей, проживающих в населенных пунктах.

Посоветуйте откуда можно получить данную информацию, либо откуда можно спарсить данные.

В голову пока только идет спарсить с википедии. Для России еще можно информацию получить вплоть для деревень, но допустим для США, там только отображаются крупнейшие города.

Comment: Да вот тут, например http://www.geonames.org/statistics/

Answer (score 1):

Вики это хороший вариант и если вы можете извлечь из него данные, то так и сделайте. Иначе можете попробовать найти через поиск готовый dataset, возможно на чьем-то гитхабе. Пример того что я нашел в поиске : [тык](https://www.maxmind.com/ru/free-world-cities-database). Можете найти компанию, которая по логике должна работать с такими данными (типа yandex.maps), связаться с ней и ласково попросить их сделать вам выгрузку, может они будут добры и потратят на это своё время) 
Всё зависит от того насколько точные и достоверные данные вам нужны, ведь если первостепенная задача стоит в создании системы, то можно просто сгенерить dataset нужного формата ([тык](http://www.generatedata.com/)) и на нём строить систему которая в дальнейшем сможет принять реальный большой dataset, о котором вы говорите.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вам придется перекопать сайты государственных статистик всех необходимых стран (если вам нужно для всего мира, то стран-членов ООН, несколько меньше 200). Есть вариант зайти на сайт [ООН](http://data.un.org/) или [ЦРУ](http://www.cia.gov), где собрана разнообразная статистика, но именно в таком разрезе... , сомневаюсь.